# How to cast : 'System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String[]]'

Tags: c#

I'm struggling with connecting these two codes:

```
//Program.cs
using System;

namespace Find_Duplicate_Files
{
    public class Finder
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var CWD = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            Console.WriteLine(CWD);
            //HashFile.Hash("Find_Duplicate_Files.exe");
            var files = Walk.From("here");
            
            foreach (var filelist in files)
            {
                foreach (var _files in filelist)
                { 
                    foreach (var file in _files)
                        Console.WriteLine(file); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
//Walk.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Find_Duplicate_Files
{
    internal class Walk
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<String[]>> From(String dir)
        {
            if (dir == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(dir);
            if (dir.ToLower() == "here")
            {
                dir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            }
            if (Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir);
                var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir);

                foreach (var d in dirs) From(d);
                yield return (IEnumerable<String[]>)files;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(dir);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to access the files, it says

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String[]]'.
```

Sadly, I don't understand anything from it.
I'm Using VS 2022, but it doesn't highlight anything else to change.

Comment: return type should be `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<String>>` instead of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<String[]>>` and cast should be `(IEnumerable<String>)` instead of `(IEnumerable<String[]>)` - notice I droped the string array in both cases so only `string` instead of `string[]`

Comment: currently you have an enumerable of enumerables of string arrays, but you "only" want an enumerable of enumerables of strings.

Comment: you should consider dropping the whole enumerable of enumerabls thing and just make it flat, so only `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: another thing `Directory.EnumerateFiles` has the option to return all files for every sub directory, by calling it like this: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.*", new EnumerationOptions() { RecurseSubdirectories = true };`

Comment: String instead of String[] works like a charm now, thank you

Comment: one last thing I noticed you are calling `From` for the subdirectories with this: `foreach (var d in dirs) From(d);` but you never do anything with the return value of the `From(d);` method